# In Linux - how do I delete a file with an 'erroneous' name?

Tags: linux, git, file-management, rm

I have a file that keeps popping up in my git status log.  It looks like it was created by accident, but when trying to use "rm name_of_file" I get the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove `name_of_file': No such file or directory
```

Here's the actual filename:

```
how
2d02b0b06030126e194e178ce2493a2de30144c7\033[1~q
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

Use escape characters.

```
rm -f "how\ 2d02b0b06030126e194e178ce2493a2de30144c7\\033[1~q"
```

Option 2:

Deleting through inum value

```
find . -inum | <operation>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using tab to autocomplete the file name? Alternatively, just use wildcards:

```
ls *how*
rm *how*
```